# XAMPP - can not access from public ip

Tags: dynamic, xampp, ip, port, forwarding

before I was accessing to my xampp server from my dynamic ip. Now I installed latest version of xampp under c:\xampp3
i have no antivirus windows firewall disabled still I can not access.
Forwarding is done correctly.

My local ip is: 192.168.0.13

*In router interface displayed WAN IP:*

**100.98.20....**

*but when I check it from browser that is:*

**94.54.225....**

if I type 100.98.20.... which is displayed in router's interface it is okay from local computer but if I type it in different net not responding.

When I type 94.54.225.... not responding from anywhere.

Whats wrong here ?

My ISP gives ips many times to each other and that is why I can not access from public ? Should I buy a static ip ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your ISP.
Your "WAN" IP is 100.98.20.... it's **IPv4 ISP: Carrier-Grade NAT RFC6598**

By the wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT

```
Disadvantages
* It makes it impossible to host services
```

Read the wiki for more details and/or contact with your ISP for public IP address.

Comment: You mean even for short connections it will not work right ? Can i buy a static ip for home use ?

Comment: Generally yes. Your curent IP 100.98.20.... works in your network / your ISP network only (in this sens - short connection should working). For public access you need public IP from ISP and port forwarding (by ISP) from this one into your 100.98.20....